# Access delegate class from QAction Trigger

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QListWidget that categorizes items and its sub-items (they are all checkable).

Currently while checking/unchecking the category items works properly for the sub items, I have introduced in a context menu in which the option should works the same way as you check and uncheck the category item.

However in my `update_opts` - the QAction in the context menu, while it does allows me to check/uncheck the category item, but it does not effects the check-state of the sub items.

Additionally, it seems that `QListWidgetItem` do not have a `trigger` or `toggle` signal that I could utilize to trigger the `editorEvent` in the delegate class.

```py
IsCategoryRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole
ParentRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1


class CategoryDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        old_state = model.data(index, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        res = super(CategoryDelegate, self).editorEvent(
            event, model, option, index
        )
        current_state = model.data(index, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if old_state != current_state:
            if index.data(IsCategoryRole):
                pix = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)
                for i in range(model.rowCount()):
                    ix = model.index(i, 0)
                    if pix == ix.data(ParentRole):
                        model.setData(
                            ix, current_state, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole
                        )
        return res


class ListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        delegate = CategoryDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    def addCategory(self, text):
        item = ListWidget.create_checkable_item(text)
        item.setData(IsCategoryRole, True)
        self.addItem(item)
        return item

    def addItemToCategory(self, category_item, text):
        item = ListWidget.create_checkable_item(text)
        item.setData(IsCategoryRole, False)
        ix = self.indexFromItem(category_item)
        pix = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(ix)
        item.setData(ParentRole, pix)
        self.addItem(item)
        return item

    @staticmethod
    def create_checkable_item(text):
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(text)
        item.setFlags(
            item.flags()
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        )
        item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        return item

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            list_menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
            selected_item = self.currentItem()
            if selected_item.data(IsCategoryRole):
                update_cat_items = QtGui.QAction("Check all or none", self)
                update_cat_items.triggered.connect(self.update_opts)
                list_menu.addAction(update_cat_items)

            list_menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor().pos())

        else:
            super(ListWidget, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def update_opts(self):
        selected_item = self.currentItem() 
        state = selected_item.checkState() # It returns eith 0 or 2, instead of QtCore.Qt.Unchecked or QtCore.Qt.Checked

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            # If opt is checked in the first place, set it to uncheck
            selected_item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

        else:
            # If opt is unchecked in the first place, set it to check
            selected_item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)


class TestDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__()
        self.listWidget = ListWidget()

        all_num = self.listWidget.addCategory("-- All Nums --")
        num_items = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
        for num in num_items:
            self.listWidget.addItemToCategory(all_num, num)

        all_letters = self.listWidget.addCategory("-- All Letters --")

        letter_items = ["A", "B", "C"]
        for letter in letter_items:
            self.listWidget.addItemToCategory(all_letters, letter)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TestDialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999394/6622587) consider that the OP only wanted that behavior should only be allowed when the user presses the checkbox, now with the new approach will extend the behavior and for this it is not necessary a delegate but to create a custom QListWidgetItem where the method is overriden setData() method:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

IsCategoryRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole
ParentRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1


class ListWidgetItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem):
    def setData(self, role, value):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole and self.data(IsCategoryRole):
            lw = self.listWidget()
            index = lw.indexFromItem(self)
            pix = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)
            for r in range(lw.count()):
                print(r)
                it = lw.item(r)
                if pix == it.data(ParentRole):
                    it.setData(role, value)
        super(ListWidgetItem, self).setData(role, value)


class ListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def addCategory(self, text):
        item = ListWidget.create_checkable_item(text)
        item.setData(IsCategoryRole, True)
        self.addItem(item)
        return item

    def addItemToCategory(self, category_item, text):
        item = ListWidget.create_checkable_item(text)
        item.setData(IsCategoryRole, False)
        ix = self.indexFromItem(category_item)
        pix = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(ix)
        item.setData(ParentRole, pix)
        self.addItem(item)
        return item

    @staticmethod
    def create_checkable_item(text):
        item = ListWidgetItem(text)
        item.setFlags(
            item.flags()
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        )
        item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        return item

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        list_menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        it = self.itemAt(self.viewport().mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor().pos()))
        if it.data(IsCategoryRole):
            update_cat_items = QtGui.QAction("Check all or none", self)
            update_cat_items.triggered.connect(self.update_opts)
            list_menu.addAction(update_cat_items)
        list_menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor().pos())

    def update_opts(self):
        it = self.itemAt(self.viewport().mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor().pos()))
        it.setCheckState(
            QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
            if it.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked
            else QtCore.Qt.Checked
        )


class TestDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__()
        self.listWidget = ListWidget()

        all_num = self.listWidget.addCategory("-- All Nums --")
        num_items = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
        for num in num_items:
            self.listWidget.addItemToCategory(all_num, num)

        all_letters = self.listWidget.addCategory("-- All Letters --")

        letter_items = ["A", "B", "C"]
        for letter in letter_items:
            self.listWidget.addItemToCategory(all_letters, letter)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TestDialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```